# White space in text - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When using Unicode text in flutter there seems to be a lot of whitespace in each character which makes it hard to align. In the code and picture below, I'm trying to get the 35m sit on the cross arrows with no space in between. I'm also trying to get the three stars at the start to center align vertically with the word starburst and then center align the (35m and arrows), starburst, and thee stars all to center align with each other vertically.

```
Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  '\u{2605}' * 3,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Starburst',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '35m',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '\u{2194}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make Row crossAxisAlignment property to CrossAxisAlignment.center

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
    children: [....
```

And

Make Column mainAxisAlignment propert to
MainAxisAlignment.center

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
    children: [...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stack` instead of `Column` and align the Text as per your UI specifications:

**Output Using Column:**

[image]

**Output Using Stack:**

[image]

Full code:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '\u{2605}' * 3,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Starburst',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28.0,
                  ),
                ),
//                 SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                Container(
                  width: 50.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          top: 4,
                          child: Text(
                            '35m',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '\u{2194}',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

You might have to tweak `Stack` widget's children a bit, but I hope this answer gives the idea.